Why $S^4$ is not symplectic; while $S^2$ is?
Whenever mathematicians try to prove $(S^{2n}, \omega)$ for $n > 1$ is not symplectic, they always invoke the Stokes' theorem and rely on the fact that $\partial S^{2n}=\varnothing$. I understand that, because $\omega^{n}$ is degenerate. Why can’t I do the same thing for $(S^2, \omega)$? It does not have a boundary too! What is it I get wrong?

The main point is that a symplectic form $\omega$ on a compact manifold $M$ gives rise to a non-zero element $\{\omega\}$ in the second cohomomology group $H^2(M,\mathbb R)$. This shows in particular that compact symplectic manifolds must have a non-trivial $H^2(M,\mathbb R)$.
To answer your question $H^2(S^{2n},\mathbb R) = 0$ when $n > 1$ so $S^{2n}$ does not admit any symplectic form. However $H^2(S^{2},\mathbb R)$ is non-zero, so there's no contradiction here (and in fact $S^2$ does carry a symplectic form).

How can I show that every two form, on $S^{2n}$ for $n > 1$, is exact? If you can give the sketch of the proof or refer me to a link that I can have a look at, I’d be glad.

I don't know if this can be shown directly. A standard way of proving this is via the so-called Mayer-Vietoris sequence. See if the following links can help:
1 - https://planetmath.org/exampleofcohomologyandmayervietorissequence
2 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence
You can also check Bott-Tu's book "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology"
